# How to get PC keybindings on the Mac

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I use a PC for most of the day and Mac at home occasionally.  Having to switch between 2 keyboard layouts is a massive brain adjustment.

Is there a way to at least to make Ctrl+Arrow act on a Mac like it does on a PC?

Bonus for Home, End, Ctrl+Home, Ctrl+End

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Goto

```
System Preferences > Keyboard & Mouse > Keyboard > Modifier Keys...
```

[image]

There you can exchange the keys.

Regarding the Home & End keys, I just found this [Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/225873/mac-switchers-tip--remap-the-home-and-end-keys) (there are a few other like this out there). It involves editing the file:

```
~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict
```

**Although not tested by me, it should work, see comments by churnd**

Comment: Awesome.  Now how do I get the Home key to go to the beginning of the line and the End key to the End of the line?

Comment: Edited the answer for Home & End keys.

Comment: I use that solution for the Home and End key to navigate beginning/end of lines, and it works for me.